# Joystick setup in Unity 2d game

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, 2d, joystick

I am using  the Unity 3D standart assets (mobile) joystick, but I have a problem when I use it in my 2D game. I have no clue, how to achieve this: when the joystick goes left or right my character to follow or when i move it up, my character to jump
So far I only have the interactive joystick working but not really moving the character.
I would really appreciate some help.
I am using the Free version of Unity.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I havent checked this video myself, but I think it can help you out.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Xnyb2f6Qqzg

Or you could use this 2D controller 
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/173640-Released-2D-Platform-Controller